# Multi-dimensional array to store and count occurrences of unique IDs

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

In trying to better understand dynamic multi-dimensional arrays, I am attempting to build one to capture unique values and count the occurrences of the unique values (something i should be able to verify pretty quickly with a countif).

In reading about trying to redim preserve a multidimensional array, I had read that you can only redim the last parameters, so I was attempting to set-up for 2 parameters, where the first is the unique value and the second is the count: arr(2,k).  If my understanding is wrong, then that also is pretty significant.

The final output of the array I am throwing into column 3 (unique ID) and column 4 (# of occurrences).

---

**Issue:**

When adding values to the array, I am not able to collect all unique values.  I have been able to collect 3 unique values, when there are 6 in the data, and the occurrences of each are staying at 1, e.g., not iterating.

---

**Question:**

I apologize that this is essentially 2 questions...

- 1)  is my use of redim preserver arr(2,0 to k) appropriate syntax?
- 2)  is there a glaring issue with my dynamic array generation which would explain why i'm not getting all unique values captured?

I could ask a third about why i can't get the occurrence count to work, but I am hopeful that if I understand the above issue I can hopefully struggle through this part.

---

**What the data looks like:**

All data is in Column A

```
cat
dog
mouse
cat
mouse
bear
frog
cat
moose
cat
dog
```

---

**Code in Question:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub unique_arr()
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long, k As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arr(2, k)
    For i = 1 To lr
        If Application.IfError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, arr, 0), 0) = 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(2, 0 To k)
            arr(1, k) = Cells(i, 1).Value
            arr(2, k) = 1
            k = k + 1
        Else
            arr(2, Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), arr(1), 0)) = arr(2, Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), arr(1), 0)) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = arr(1, i)
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = arr(2, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: ...In hindsight, I could use the Match() for the above data and only add if it's found found, e.g., application.match(cells(i,1).value,range(cells(1,1),cells(i-1,1)),0)... but would need to start on row 2 to avoid the error

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? A pivot table could do this quickly and easily.

Comment: @tigeravatar this is purely to help understand how to reference/use the multidimensional array with a (relatively) simple procedure.  I recognize there are easier ways to perform this specific task, but it was one that I felt would give me the biggest bang for my buck, so to speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you would be better off overall with a dictionary, there are a few things wrong with the If comparison.

```
If Application.IfError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, arr, 0), 0) = 0 Then
```

VBA has its own IsError that returns True/False.

```
If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, arr, 0), 0)) Then
```

Additionally, arr is a 2-D array; in essence it has both rows and columns. The worksheet's Match can only work on a single column or a single row. You need to 'slice' off what you want with Index.

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, application.index(arr, 1, 0), 0), 0)) Then
```

Finally, *arr* is defined as `ReDim arr(2, k)`. This makes it `arr(0 to 2, 0 to k)` so there are three elements in the first rank (*0, 1, 2*), not 2. You never actually use the 0 in the first rank. It should be,

```
k = 1
ReDim arr(1 to 2, 1 to k)
```

Wind it all up and you end up with something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub unique_arr()
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, k As Long, arr As Variant, m As Variant

    'assign values to some vars
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 1
    ReDim arr(1 To 2, 1 To k)

    'loop through cells, finding duplicates and counting
    For i = 1 To lr
        m = Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, Application.Index(arr, 1, 0), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 2, 1 To k)
            arr(1, k) = Cells(i, 1).Value
            arr(2, k) = 1
            k = k + 1
        Else
            arr(2, m) = arr(2, m) + 1
        End If
    Next i

    'loop through array's second rank
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(1, i)
        Cells(i, 4).Value = arr(2, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach and explanation for how to do this using arrays per the OP's request, +1

Comment: New contributor and providing well written instructions?!  You are quite the unicorn (not to be confused with eunich horn).  I appreciate the explanation regarding the non-usage of the 0 in the first dimension; that was a big key in getting this to work.  Also, my apologies for being lazy with the application.iferror()... i catch myself often overlooking the usage of boolean for if statements

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I'd use a Dictionary, like so:

```
Sub ExtractUniqueCounts()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim hUnq As Object

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set hUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Create Dictionary object

    'Loop through populated cells in column A
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        'Ignore blanks
        If Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then
            'Check if this is a new, unique value that hasn't been added yet
            If Not hUnq.Exists(rCell.Value) Then
                'New unique value found, add to dictionary and set count to 1
                hUnq(rCell.Value) = 1
            Else
                'Not a unique value, increase existing count
                hUnq(rCell.Value) = hUnq(rCell.Value) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    'Check if there are any results
    If hUnq.Count > 0 Then
        'Results found
        'Output the keys (unique values)
        ws.Range("C1").Resize(hUnq.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(hUnq.keys)

        'Output the values of the keys (the counts in this case)
        ws.Range("D1").Resize(hUnq.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(hUnq.items)
    Else
        'No results, return error
        MsgBox "No data"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown on use of Dictionary.  I appreciate the commenting on this, as I am aware that dictionary could also perform this specific task.  I was very much trying to understand appropriate usage of setting and dynamically increasing the multidimensional array and trying to move that bit of my understanding forward.  I will say my big takeaway from this is related to using Transpose for outputting the data.  That is a huge time saver!

Comment: Another lesson about the Dictionary. Now I'm visualizing like an array is a Worksheet, but a dictionary is only the first two rows (hence Transpose), although for unique values lightning fast.